# Multiplayer ping-pong game using websockets and canvas

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, socket.io, html5-canvas

I am creating a multiplayer ping pong ball game using sockets.io and html5 canvas.

My node server is calculating ball position (x,y) and sending it to canvas at client at 30 fpr.

My question is is it posible to send 30 messages per second to client using websocket? My server and client are located at very far(server at us and brower at australia).

Please suggest me if it can be done by any other better way.

Comment: be careful with pong like games, Atari take them very seriously. I'm 16 and I received a letter from their solicitors for making a pong 'like' app on the Appstore.

Comment: "browser at australia" - correct me if i am wrong, but performance in australia is "down under" ...

Comment: Yes Andreas I am concern about performance.

Comment: Jordan I am sorry I am not going to creating iPhone application, I am creating website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes a persistent connection like websockets is your best bet here.   There's no magic for high latency though, some reason you can't have servers where your customers are?

Comment: Yes I can put my server where my custumers are, but still will it be pisible to get 30 fps using websickets and html5-canvas??

Comment: @user1197280 -- FPS is not the problem. With pong, you could get 300fps, if you didn't use `.requestAnimationFrame`. The problem is RTT : 'round trip time, the time it takes for information to go from a client to the server and back to the client with the new data. There is no magic wand which can make a player in India talk to a server in the US which talks to a player in Australia... the data has to go all the way from one point to the next to the next. If your server was beside you, and the two players were in your livingroom, then yes, 100-tick would be fine, even. But AU->US->... ??

Comment: @Norguard thanks. If I build the for indian users and my server is in india then would it posible to send 30 messages containing ball's xy per second to client?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want us to tell you - in a perfect world you could send a million messages per second.   You will need to test this.  Websocket is the best available option here, so try it out.

Comment: Thanks for you response I will try this and will post here.

Comment: I have used socket.io and it works for me thanks everyone how posted here.